# User do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_cart]' ) leads to default Ajax update not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on woo commerce project, when I create a page and add shortcode [woocommerce_cart] in the content editor, the cart update function by using Ajax working fine. but when I am including the  cart by echo do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_cart]' ),  Ajax update is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need to setup woocommerce cart page in woocommerce admin settings.
WooCommerce only works with pages that are defined

Go to this link :
wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=advanced

and select cart page